# Only able to acces req.user on the POST request right after authenticating him and not later in the code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

When I send a post request and use `passport.authenticate` I can access the `req.user` but then when I am actually trying to `console.log()` the user later in the code (on the "/user" route) it returns undefined.

```
router.post(
  '/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureRedirect: '/',
  }),
  (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.user);
    res.redirect('/');
  }
);

router.get('/user', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.user);
  res.send(req.user);
});
```

I tried deleting the cookies maxAge in the `expressSession` parameters since someone recommended it on another question but it didn't work and nothing changed.

Comment: Do you have `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` configured? If so could you add that code as well?

Comment: Here is the passportconfig: 
 passport.serializeUser((user, cb) => {
    cb(null, user.username);
  });
  passport.deserializeUser((username, cb) => {
    User.findOne({ username: username })
      .then((doc) => {
        cb(null, doc);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
};

Comment: For `deserializeUser` how do you know the first parameter is username? Can you console.log the variable before `User.findOne` to confirm its the value you are expecting?